# How to send sms from android app to mobile?

Tags: android, sms, android-sms

I have tried this code but I did not receive SMS in my phone.

```java
    Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);  
    PendingIntent pi=PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent,0);  

    //Get the SmsManager instance and call the sendTextMessage method to send message                 
    SmsManager sms=SmsManager.getDefault();  
    sms.sendTextMessage("88xxxxxxx0", null, "hello javatpoint", pi,null);
```

Comment: Have you declared required permissions in your manifest?

Comment: yes i have declared permissions. my msgs are sent but not receive in my phone

Comment: please help me...

Comment: If they're sent properly, then it must be the problem in your receiving phone. Sometimes due to system killing background services you don't receive notification. I myself have to keep my SMS application open to receive SMS.

Comment: nothing happen...still i have open my messaging app in my phone....

Comment: is there other solution or technique ?

Comment: Did you try the code given by Kunchana Roshintha? Are you receiving SMS_DELIVERED after the SMS is sent?

Comment: yes i have done that code also... but msg not receive

Comment: Do you have Github repo for the code?

Comment: repo means? i didnt get it

Comment: There is a website called Github to share your projects online and so that other people could see your code. You create a repository in your github profile and share it with other people to see.

Comment: May i share with u? Can you check my code for a while?

Comment: Sure. I'll check it out.

Comment: https://github.com/prachivankawala/smsapp

Comment: I'll check it out

Comment: Have u found any mistake?

Comment: Yes, you're not requesting any permissions before trying to send the message. You'll have to add code to request permission before you're actually sending the message

Comment: please send me your code... i m not aware about that concept

Comment: You can use Intent to simplify sending sms. Instead of using all that code to manage SMS permissions, as well as handling the code to send SMS, you can launch SMS intent to start SMS handler app in your device

Comment: You can do that with this simple Intent, as follows: startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.fromParts("sms", number, null))); You don't have to edit "sms" in the URI section, you just have to pass the number that you want to send SMS to.

Answer (score 0):

You can send message from your application through this:

```
public void sendSMS(String MoNo, String msg) {
    try {      
        SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
        smsManager.sendTextMessage(MoNo, null, msg, null, null);    
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Message Sent",
              Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),ex.getMessage().toString(),
              Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } 
}
```

Also you need to give SEND_SMS permission in AndroidManifest.xml to send message

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
```

Thanks. Happy Coding...